# Hash table - adding a rehash to resize method

Tags: c++, algorithm, hashmap

I'm doing hash table with chaining and can't figure out how should I rehash whole table while resizing. I was thinking about inserting all elements with new hashcode in resize method, but I have no idea how to... Could you give me a hint or something?
Here is rehash (I mean resize, without rehashing yet) method:

```
void rehash()
{
    if (current_size >= load * size) {
        int newsize = size * cap;
        Node** tmp = new Node * [newsize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            tmp[i] = hashtable[i];
        }
        for (int i = size; i < newsize; ++i) 
        {
            tmp[i] = NULL;
        }
        delete[] hashtable;
        hashtable = tmp;
        size = newsize;
    }
}
```

and, if thats helpful, inserting method:

```
void addTo(string key, V value)
{
    rehash();
    int index = hashFunction(key);
    if (hashtable[index] == NULL)
    {
        Node* newpair = new Node(key, value);
        hashtable[index] = newpair;
        hashtable[index]->data = newpair;
    }
    else
    {
        Node* tmp = hashtable[index];
        Node* newpair = new Node(key, value);
        Node* newnode = new Node;
        newnode->data = newpair;
        newnode->next = NULL;
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
        {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = newnode;
        
    }
    current_size++;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: When you increase the table size, some of the values should probably go into the rear part of the new table, where `size <= i < newsize`. You could keep a handle to the old table, allocate a fresh table of the new size with all `NULL`s, and walk the old table and insert all entries into the new table with `addTo`. Then delete the old table.

Comment: I recommend a structured approach: say your class is called `hash_table`, then when you realise you need to increase capacity, create a new `hash_table` - specifying a larger table size to the constructor - then iterate over the current elements inserting each one into the new `hash_table`,  then `swap(*this, ` with the new `hash_table`.  That way you're re-using functions you should already have working - constructor, iteration, insert, swap - for a fixed-sized table.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I understand now what should I do, but can't figure out how to use my addTo method with fresh table

Comment: Apparently, you have one global hashtable that is defined by `table` and `size` and all your functions operate on these variables. Your code creates a new array, then sets these variables. If you do it the other way round -- keep the old table in local variables and set the global hash table to the fresh array -- you can then use the functions you have already to populate the new table.

Comment: (But my suggestion to use `addTo` isn't ideal, because it creates new nodes and you'd have to delete the old ones. A better solution would be to just move the nodes to their new buckets. Because you already know that you have no duplicate keys (but your insertion function dosn't enforce that), you can just insert the nodes as the new head of each bucket.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increase the size of your hash table, the associated buckets may change for some keys. Your code just copies the lists from the front part, which means that some values can no longer be found in the table. (For example a key with hash code 13 will have the index 1 in a table of size 4, but the index will change to 5 after increasing the size to 8.)

Your basic approach to allocate a new array is correct, but you must place the nodes in their correct buckets. Becsuae you have a linked list, you can visit each bucket of the old table and extract the first node while there is one and then put it into the bucket with the right new index:

```
void rehash()
{
    if (current_size >= load * size) {
        size_t newsize = size * cap;
        Node** tmp = new Node * [newsize];

        for (size_t i = 0; i < newsize; ++i) {
            tmp[i] = NULL;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            while (hashtable[i]) {
                Node *node = hashtable[i];
                size_t index = hashFunction(node->key);

                // remove node from old table ...
                hashtable[i] = node->next;

                // ... and insert into new one
                node->next = tmp[index];
                tmp[index] = node;                    
            }
        }

        // replace hash table
        delete[] hashtable;
        hashtable = tmp;
        size = newsize;
    }
}
```

This shold work. (But I haven't tested it.)